# What data format is that and how can i read out it via PHP?

Tags: php, json, magento, session-cookies

I've search and search but what is this for a DATA FORMAT:?

```
a:6:{s:14:"component_mode";s:6:"aswdas";s:14:"payment_method";s:0:"";s:16:"channel_order_id";s:5:"75614";s:17:"channel_final_fee";i:0;s:12:"transactions";a:0:{}s:6:"tax_id";N;}
```

I find it in Magento in a Order Export und "additional_data",

and in Magento session data itself:

```
mobileswitcher_admin|a:1:{s:23:"_session_validator_data";a:4:{s:11:"remote_addr";s:0:"";s:8:"http_via";s:0:"";s:20:"http_x_forwarded_for";s:0:"";s:15:"http_user_agent";s:0:"";}}
```

How can I get the data from that string? Is it a JSON like format?
Is there any function I can use to encode/decode?

Thanks in advance!

Tyv

Comment: it's serialized date. serialize(). you can use unserialize() to "decode" it.

Comment: its JSON, you can use json decode or json encode along with foreach loop to iterate on internal data

Comment: On php.net I find information on it, but when I try to unserialize the data I get a "Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'compononent_mode' (T_STRING):

Comment: Mangesh Sathe: What do you mean?  In my first example beginning with "a:6{s:14..." - How can I loop over it with json encode?

Comment: tried and it works. You an see the data here.  http://www.unserialize.com/
For information in Magento 2.2 now everything uses json encode instead of serialize (finally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a serialized array

you can use 
`unserialize()` to convert it into an array